# Inserting values to database while typing

Tags: jquery, jsp

I have a task.I want to insert data into database while typing values in textbox....

Even I don't know is it possible. Is it possible?
Any example will be appreciated.

Comment: it is possible. you need to attach keyup event for input box and make ajax call to save text to the database. Please share some relevant code whenever you post a question, this way we can help you in better way.

Comment: take a look at angular.js

Comment: @Hiru this does not help the OP if you not explain why this will be relevant.

Comment: @Shan is there a reason why this needs to be updated to the database every time the user enters something? Can't you store the value in cache and after focus out save it into the database?

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar: Ya,I know but i have an idea only.... here after only i have to execute this idea...i have a question.

Comment: @Mivaweb But i have to run this program with different machines...When some person enter the value in one system i have to save the value in my system database

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar Can you please explain with some example...Bcoz i am newbie to jsp,jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it possible to do that. Here example for you, but in PHP way. You can change into JSP by using this references.

**Html**

```
<input type="text" id="hey">
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#hey').on('keyup', function(){    
   $.ajax({
      type : 'POST',
      url : 'insertData.php', // --> server side code to insert data into db
      data : {
        val : $(this).val()
      },
      success : function(msg){
        // msg -> return by server side
        // any code in success
        // if success will print out this 'New record created successfully'
        // if error will print out this 'Error occured'
        console.log(msg);
      }
  });
});
```

**Php - insertData.php**

```
 <?php
 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "username";
 $password = "password";
 $dbname = "myDB";

 // Create connection
 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);     

 $sql = "INSERT INTO comment (myText)
 VALUES (".$_POST['val'].")";

 if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
   echo "New record created successfully";
 } else {
   echo "Error occured";
 }

 $conn->close();
 ?>
```

Comment: Thanks a loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooootttttttttttttttttttttttttt :-)

Comment: @ShanBagam : welcome.. Just do that man. And never forget to accept this as answer if it help you. Cheers.

Comment: I have one doubt...If i change the value while typing means is keyup function will accept ah?

Comment: yes. Those function will trigger every time keyup event detected after typing something on `#hey` id. You can change the event as you like, just replace the event that available out there in jQuery DOC.